# c++ code block ok but still get not compile

Tags: c++, c

```
int* areaofsquare(int len,int width){
    int value = len*width;
    return &value;
}

int main() {
    printf("area=%i\n",*areaofsquare(1,2));
    return 0;

}
```

Why I get memory error from this code? As per my understanding I did not get any error in this code block so why does it not run properly?

Help me out.
Thank you.

Comment: Address [the warning](https://godbolt.org/z/khOKOi)

Comment: `area` falls out of scope the instant that function returns, so returning a pointer to it is to return an invalid pointer. Turn on `-Wall` when compiling.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just return pointer to stack variable, as it's getting invalidated as the function returns. You can use dynamic memory allocation instead:

```
int* area(int leangth,int width){
    int * area = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *area = leangth*width;
    return area;
}

int main() {
    printf("area=%i\n",*area(5,6));
}
```

Please note that you create memory leak and it would be better to handle it some way, but in this tiny example it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the address of a local function variable in your function `area`. When the function returns, its stack space is no longer valid, so attempting to access an address to a local variable from that function is undefined behavior.

I don't see why you need to make `area` return a pointer to an int. Just return `area`'s value and have `area`'s return type just be `int` instead.

If for some reason you are required to return a pointer to an `int` (i.e. assignment or deliverable specifications), you have some options:

1. Use heap memory. Allocate `area` with `malloc`, and `free` it in `main` after you've printed its value.
2. Use `static` to put `area` into the process' data section rather than in stack memory, so that it persists beyond its scope and an address-of operation on it will continue to work after the function returns.